# How can you figure out the type signature of (a reference to) a function?

Tags: rust, type-signature

I have a few implementations of a function that I would like to test.  To do that cleanly, I want to put references to them into an array and call them one by one.  Due to recent syntax changes, to do this, you need to first explicitly cast functions to function references with correct type signatures.  Since the syntax you use to declare a function is different from its actual type, this is a non-trivial task.

How do you figure out the type of a reference to a Rust function with non-trivial signature (e.g. it involves generics, lifetimes, takes another function, etc.)?

A particular [function](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3f50a4b5811ecf13dbda43f9fab4339b&version=undefined) (which I wrote) was declared with signature:

```
pub fn take_while2<'a,T,F:Fn(&T)->bool >(initial: &'a [T], predicate: F) -> Option<&'a [T]> {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least, not with that function.

First of all, you have can't have a generic variable.  That is, `x` can't depend on `T`.  To take a simpler example:

```
fn test<T>(_: &T) { unimplemented!() }

fn main() {
    let x: fn(&u8) = test;
}
```

This works because the compiler can infer the concrete type `T` is (in this case, `u8`).  So why can't you do that?  Because of `F`.  You're asking for a closure type, and closure types are *anonymous*; no matter what you do, you can't name one.  If you managed to get the type system to *infer* the closure type, it would only be valid for *exactly* one specific closure.  Much like functions, each closure has its own unique type, even if it is *literally* the same.  Unlike functions, closures don't have a common base type you can use.

It's hard to give any recommendations without knowing what it is you're actually trying to accomplish.  To take a stab in the dark, however, you might want to try something like:

```
pub fn take_while2<'a,T>(initial: &'a [T], predicate: Box<Fn(&T) -> bool>) -> Option<&'a [T]> { // '
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    let functions: Vec<for<'a> fn(&'a [u8], Box<Fn(&u8) -> bool>) -> Option<&'a [u8]>> = vec![take_while2]; // '
    // ...
}
```

Note the use of `for<'a>` which is a higher-ranked lifetime, which has the same function as the `'a` generic parameter for the `take_while2` definition.  *Also* note that this syntax *does not* work for type arguments.

Credit to Shepmaster for reminding me that you can *also* use `&Fn(&T) -> bool` instead of a boxed closure.  That lifts the requirement of a heap allocation for the caller.

This will also require you to box any closures you want to pass to `predicate`.

Comment: You could also accept a trait object as a reference (`&Fn(&T) -> bool`) instead of needing to heap-allocate.

Comment: @Shepmaster: You know, I *completely* forgot about those.  *To the Editmobile!*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer!  It is going to take me a while to understand what the heck is going on, though. Somewhere in the run-up to alpha, rust flew over my head in complexity.  Is Fn the type of a function you declare with fn?  What does it mean for one to be in a Box?  Does that mean the local variables are all allocated on the heap whenever you call the function?

Comment: @AndrewWagner: Functions have a `fn` type.  `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce` are three "callable" traits which are implemented by things you can call, which includes functions as well as closures.  Boxing something does put it on the heap.  Basically, you can't use traits by-value, so you need *some kind* of indirection, be that a box or a borrowed reference.  It's a bit much to go into in a comment.